# customization of controllers' redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, paperclip

I'm using devise gem to CRUD my users

there is a image - avatar - I want to process with papercliop after user have edited his profile(registration). So to do that I want to render him certain template from update action in registraition controller - which inherit from Devise::RegistrationsController. I don't know details of update method implementation so I invoke super method - it redirects user, consequently, 'render' causes double render error

is there any 'magic' way's to invoke all savings of model without devise redirecting

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can redefine `after_update_path_for` in `RegistrationsController` https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L98

Comment: I've already impemented that way, but I want to RENDER some page, but devise allow just to redirect to arbitrary page with after_update_path_for. thank you though!